# Equivalent of substring in Impala

Tags: sql, impala, dbvisualizer

```
-- else left(wof.ro_end_date, 4) + '-' + 
        substring(cast(wof.ro_end_date as varchar(20)), 5, 2) + '-' +
        right(wof.ro_end_date, 2)
```

This is the code that was originally used in SQL Server Management Studio. Is there any way to do this in the Impala data lake?

Comment: `SUBSTR` function?

Comment: Hive and Impala are two different things

Comment: sorry mistyped in the title im working in impala

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
substr(cast(wof.ro_end_date as string),5,2) + '-' + strright(wof.ro_end_date, 2)
```